# How to execute methods in Java in a certain order without using a main method?

Tags: java, libgdx

This is sort of like LibGDX. It has an Application interface and an ApplicationListener interface. The methods create(), render(), pause(), resume(), and dispose() are somehow magically executed (at least to me it seems that way) without being called anywhere. How is this possible? Did I miss something? I have a basic knowledge of Java, but maybe I missed something.

The source can be viewed here at https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/tree/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a tutorial for writing an application with libGDX:
https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ApplicationConfiguration

As it states for the sample application, you actually need to write 
a main method yourself and create a LwjglApplicationthere specifying your ApplicationListener:

```
public class MyFirstTriangleDesktop {
    public static void main (String[] argv) {
        LwjglApplicationConfiguration cfg = new LwjglApplicationConfiguration();
        cfg.title = "my-gdx-game";
        cfg.useGL20 = false;
        cfg.width = 480;
        cfg.height = 320;

        new LwjglApplication(new MyGdxGame(), cfg);           
    }
}
```

You can see how methods you mention are then called by the LwjglApplication class in the source file: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglApplication.java

EDITED: Updated deprecated tutorial link

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a "runner" provided by the LibGDX framework.  For instance, there are runners that are designed for running as an ordinary Java application, an Android application, a GWT application or (apparently) an iOS application.

References:

- "Running the demo & and test apps" in http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/documentation.html
- "Running your application" in http://code.google.com/p/libgdx/wiki/ProjectSetupNew

... or you could write your own simple launcher: see Lake's answer.